# Visual studio has gone crazy trying to create files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, process-monitor

I downloaded Process Monitor and began monitoring my project directory that I am writing code in.

I see endless entries every couple seconds of:

```
Operation: Create File
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\csharp
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\code
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\web
```

and so on for the rest of the templates

Then it says the result is `PATH NOT FOUND`.

What is happening?  Has Visual Studio GONE CRAZY?!?!?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: Yes, that's one of the first signs that Visual Studio is about to go on a rampage. You'd better get out of the building while you still can.

Comment: My guess is, background compiling and intellisense creation. Looking for any new files.

Comment: This happens to me only when I have the Solution Explorer open while debugging.  I can reproduce this fairly easily just by opening it.  it's not 100% of the time, but it happens often enough that I just close the Solution Explorer.  I sort of assumed that this is why the Solution Explorer is hidden when you debug by default...  Is this where it's happening for you?

Comment: More information... createfile also means open file.  Why is it trying to open these file in my project directory instead of the actual location of the templates directory?  What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, background compiling and intellisense creation. Looking for any new files.